# C++ BigInteger and Assignment Operator Overloading

Tags: c++

I have to build a BigInteger class in C++. The BigInt has to be stored in an array with fixed size. I am now wondering, whether it is possible to overload the assignment operator to accept a number bigger than long long int on the right hand side (but internally storing the integers in an array).

Example:

BigInteger i = 1000000000000000010000000000000000010000000000000000100000000000;

and internally it might be stored like:

i.data = {10000000000000000,100000000000000000,10000000000000000,100000000000};

Is this possible? This is how far I've come:

```
#include "BigIntegerF.h"
using namespace std;

// Default Constructor
BigIntegerF::BigIntegerF() {
    data[0] = 0;
}

// Destructor
BigIntegerF::~BigIntegerF(){}

BigIntegerF& BigIntegerF::operator = (const BigIntegerF& bigInt) 
{
    // don't know how i could implement it here
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing it? Do you know how to overload `operator=`? If yes then what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Please note: you probably don't want to override the assignment operator, copy constructor, destructor and the like. This is also known as "rule of zero", explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [user-defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal):

```
BigInteger operator ""_bigInt(char const *str, std::size_t len) {
    // Create and return a BigInteger from the string representation
}
```

Then you can create a `BigInteger` as follows:

```
auto myBigInt = 1234567890_bigInt;
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ has the `operator ""` syntax for exactly these cases, where you want to create a user-defined object out of a literal in code (see [answer by Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830478/509868)).

If your compiler doesn't support the relatively new `operator ""` syntax (e.g. MS Visual Studio 2013 and older), you can use slightly less convenient syntax, which involves an initializer-list:

```
class BigInteger
{
public:
    ...

    BigInteger(std::initializer_list<unsigned long long> list)
    {
        std::copy(list.begin(), list.end(), data);
        size = list.size();
    }

private:
    ...
    unsigned long long data[999];
    size_t size;
};
```

Use it as follows:

```
BigInteger i{100000, 2358962, 2398572389, 2389562389};
```

Comment: "If your compiler doesn't support the relatively new operator "" syntax (e.g. MS Visual Studio)" - Visual Studio (at least 2015 & 2017) supports User Defined Literals just fine.

Comment: Updated with details